# data format of /scan

Tags: ros, scan

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi all,
I'm using ROS INDIGO. I used depthimage_to_laserscan to obtain scan data. what does the values under /scan represent? is it the range from the obstacles(metres or centimetres).?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/227242/data-format-of-/scan/) by [David John](https://answers.ros.org/users/25457/david-john/) on ROS Answers with karma: 19 on 2016-02-21

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

That particular node is actually pretty well documented. From [wiki/depthimage_to_laserscan - Node - depthimage_to_laserscan - Published topics](http://wiki.ros.org/depthimage_to_laserscan#Published_Topics):

> 2.1.2 Published Topics

> `scan` ([sensor_msgs/LaserScan](http://docs.ros.org/api/sensor_msgs/html/msg/LaserScan.html))

> The output laser scan. Follows [REP 117](http://ros.org/reps/rep-0117.html), and will output range arrays that contain NaNs and +-Infs.

If you follow the link to the `sensor_msgs/LaserScan` documentation, it should be pretty clear.

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-02-21

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1